# Error in paste(query, format, sep = ".") : cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character' in R

Tags: r

```
BASE_URL <- "https://content.guardianapis.com/search?to"   
api_key <-"&api-key=xxxxxxx" 
to_date <- "-date=2019-12-15"   
from_date <-"&from-date=2014-01-16" 
content <- "&q=Microsoft"

#construct URL 
query <- paste(BASE_URL, to_date, from_date, content, api_key,sep=",")
URL <- paste(query, format, sep = ".")
```

Hello. I would like to ask why I have received an error stating the following statement when I tried to paste the query into the URL.

> Error in paste(query, format, sep = ".") :    cannot coerce type
>   'closure' to vector of type 'character'

Comment: Is `format` a variable?  You're currently trying to `paste` a `string` to a `function`

Comment: Oh, I got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach using `sprintf` that makes it easier to see what parameters are being used

```
SPRINT_URL <- "https://content.guardianapis.com/search?to,&date=%s,&from-date=%s,&q=%s,&api-key=%s"
sprintf(SPRINT_URL, "2019-12-15", "2014-01-16", "Microsoft", "xxxxxxx")

[1] "https://content.guardianapis.com/search?to,&date=2019-12-15,&from-date=2014-01-16,&q=Microsoft,&api-key=xxxxxxx"
```

The above code appears not to work because it's trying to `paste` a `string` to a `function`